# How to Update/replace image in WPF by clicking button

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have an image that when the user clicks on a button it will change it to a new item. However, whenever the user clicks on one of the button, the window will go blank. How can I get this to work? Thank you.

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (imageNumber > 6)
    {
        imageNumber = 1;
    }
    imageNumber++;
    string sUri = string.Format("@/Resources/{0}", imageSource[imageNumber]);
    Uri src = new Uri(sUri, UriKind.Relative);
    var bmp = new BitmapImage(src);
    img.Source = bmp;            
}
```

xaml

```
<Image x:Name="img">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/BlackJackTut-1.jpg" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: The @ looks rather malplaced if you ask me :p

Comment: Shouldn't the @ go before the quotes, to use verbatim strings and avoid having to escape the slashes?

Comment: One of you heroes should post that as an actual answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF application you can do same also with `"pack://application:,,,/resources/imagename.png"`.
This way called [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is static, but with these code you can do same an even use resource ;)

Put image in Resources.

```
private BitmapImage ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

and then use this:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Img.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(Properties.Resources.iamge1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an Image outside the mainWindow.

Then:

```
myImageOnScreen.Source = myImageOffScreen.Source;
```